# Is it possible to type accented letters using the Galaxy S English keyboard?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, keyboard, languages, localization

I have a Galaxy S, and my locale is English (UK). Is it possible to type accented letters, such as **é** to a textfield using the keyboard? If yes, how?

edit: I know I can use swype but please don't recommend it because my native language is not supported by Swype and it's really not comfortable to use swype in my case

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure if it is the same on all devices, but if you long press on the letter e then you should see a pop-up that allows you to selected accented variations of the letter e.
Example: ā ñ ī ē õ ū ķ even ś and it won't give you an option that doesn't go with the letter.

Comment: May I know what your model is? Mine is Galaxy S, apparently Samsung has a custom keyboard, and that doesn't work

Comment: The long press works on the HTC keyboard (Desire HD), and on the version of the Swipe beta I have installed.

Comment: @Friti Galaxy S comes with Swype keyboard, right? I have it installed on Motorola Milestone, and the long press works perfectly. Maybe it is the language?

Comment: it works with the Swype keyboard, but not with the default keyboard

Comment: This works on my Galaxy S using the custom Samsung keyboard.

Comment: not with me. May I know your selected locale and language?

Comment: @Fitri Works for me too on a UK Galaxy S i9000, running official Samsung Froyo release, using the Samsung Keyboard as input method, and locale set to "English (United Kingdom)" and the Samsung Keyboard Input Language set to "English (UK)" and portrait keyboard type set to "Qwerty Keypad"

Comment: Works fine here too. Using Finnish Galaxy S i9000, latest official Froyo (JPA), Samsung keyboard with English(US) layout and locale. Just need to long press for letter variants (àáâãåäæ).

Comment: As Luke Dunstan answers: but if I remember well, you do need to have Froyo (2.2) installed. I don't think I had the accented characters when I had Android 2.1 runnding on my Galaxy s.

Comment: Weird... I don't have that. I'm using English (UK) as locale and "English" as language

Comment: @Luke Dunstan: Are you running Froyo (look at my answer to this question) ?